# undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I have a problem with my code.
I have such an info trying to build:

```
g++ -L /usr/local/boost_1_55_0 -Wall -pedantic -Iinc -c -lboost_system -pthread -lboost_thread  -o obj/glo.o src/glo.cpp

g++ -L /usr/local/boost_1_55_0 -Wall -pedantic -Iinc -c -lboost_system -pthread -lboost_thread  -o obj/serial.o src/serial.cpp

g++ -I /usr/local/boost_1_55_0 -Wall -lboost_system -pthread -o dwa obj/glo.o obj/serial.o

obj/glo.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
glo.cpp:(.text+0x15a): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
glo.cpp:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
glo.cpp:(.text+0x172): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
obj/glo.o: In function `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
glo.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6system10error_codeC2Ev[_ZN5boost6system10error_codeC5Ev]+0x17): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

and similar.

As You can see I have given

```
-lboost_system -pthread -lboost_thread  and compiled system boost in /usr/local/boost_1_55_0
```

I have no idea whats happening.

Comment: Try moving `-lboost_system` to the *end* of the line.

Comment: It worked form me! Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, g++ cannot find library boost_system. It should locate in /usr/local/boost_1_55_0/lib. You can add option "-v" to check the detailed error messages.

```
g++ -v -L/usr/local/boost_1_55_0/lib -Wall -lboost_system -pthread -o dwa obj/glo.o obj/serial.o
```

The commands should be as following:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/boost_1_55_0/include -Wall -pedantic -Iinc -c -o obj/glo.o src/glo.cpp

g++ -I/usr/local/boost_1_55_0/include -Wall -pedantic -Iinc -c -o obj/serial.o src/serial.cpp

g++ -L/usr/local/boost_1_55_0/lib -Wall -lboost_system -pthread -o dwa obj/glo.o obj/serial.o
```

Comment: I will check it, thnx